# Array of arrays and variable name based on object property

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, ajax

I call ajax service and I got back collection of objects. Object *(A)* properties are **Group, order, salary**. Let's say `[Employee, 1, 1500],[Management, 2, 2000], [Employee, 3, salary]` are my objects.

I need to to create an array for every **group** that can hold different objects *(B)*, these objects could have format `[OrderNo, String]` and will be also retrieved by ajax call. If an array for a **group** was already created I do not want to call ajax for it again.

Problem is number of objects *(A)* or *(B)* isn't known in advance and I have to be able to reference the *(A)* object arrays and list thru them.

**Result in pseudo code**

```
var groups = [
    Employee: [[1372, "Free meals"],[947, "Lower salary"],[21, "Overtimes"],[74667,"Great Xmass party"]],
    Management: [[11, "Responsibility"],[485,"Extra meetings"]]
]
```

I don't know how to correctly write

```
for(var index in "Object A"){
if(groups.AlreadyContains("Object A[index]")){
     do nothing;
}
else {
     var "Object A[index]" = MyAjaxCall("Object A[index]");
     groups.AddAnArray("Object A[index]");
    }
}

function MyAjaxCall(par){ call ajax and return collection of B objects;}

foreach(var i in groups.Management)
{Console.log(Management[i].PropertyName);}
```

Console output: Responsibility, Extra meetings

Answer (score 0):

You need to get both objects of type A and objects of type B ready and then start computation over them.

This is a common pattern in async functionality.

If you are using ES6

```
Promise.all(fetchObjectA, fetchObjectsB).then((objectsA, objectsB) =>
  // Do things over both objectsA and B
)
```

If you are using jQuery

```
$.when(fetchObjectA, fetchObjectsB).done((objectsA, objectsB) =>
   // Do same as above
)
```